# Cloud CDN for Internal (intranet) Web Site

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

I want to use CDN for caching of static assets for an intranet app currently hosted on GCP.
However this site is only available with privately and has no external access. I understand for CDN I need to have external HTTP load balancer and since external load balancers can only be used for external sites with external IPs, I assume I can't really use CDN of any kind? So my best option is to just host it on Google Cloud Storage buckets?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create an external load balancer over an instance group who's VMs don't have external IPs, but it would still be exposing the app on an external address.
Buckets might be the way you want to go.